# ogr2ogr conversion from pbf to mapbox mvt

Tags: gdal, api, pbf

I have downloaded traffic data from TomTom API which has come in the format `https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/relative0/12/1207/1539.pbf?tileSize=256&key=*****`

The PBF format is Google Protobuf, which is entirely different to Mapbox PBF
I want to show the data vector tiles on MapBox which is requesting it in MVT format so I've tried `ogr2ogr`

`>ogr2ogr -f MVT output/data.mvt input/data.gpkg`

but that is outputting an MVT folder with numerous subfolders containing PBFs. I assumed the format would've been {z}/{x}/{y}.mvt

Is GDAL able to convert PBF into the appropriate Mapbox MVT format?

Answer (score 1):

The .pbf vector tiles and .mvt vector tiles are the same. From https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/guides/vector-tiles-standards/

> Vector tiles are encoded as Google Protobufs (PBF), which allow for
> serializing structured data. For clarity, Mapbox Vector Tiles use the
> .mvt file suffix.

Mapbox changed the recommended suffix in 2016 when the version 2 of the specification was introduced. See https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/issues/69.

> Once we release the new specification we will be supporting the .mvt
> extension and encouraging people to use it.
>
> ...
>
> After our upgrade the
> .vector.pbf extension will still work and will serve v2 tiles going
> forward from Mapbox.

You will get `{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf` by concatenating `mainfolder/subfolder/filename.pbf` There should be no need for renaming the files by changing the suffix .pbf into .mvt but you can do it if you wish.

Comment: thanks for this, however my tiles still aren't appearing in the correct location which is making me think that the conversion from the api format to mapbox format is incorrect

Comment: I wonder why do you want to make a conversion because the tiles from tomtom are already in the same format despite the suffix is .pbf instead of .mvt.

Comment: because the api downloads one single pbf file which is appearing off the coast of africa for me at the moment. It should be located within the UK - so I assumed the format of the downloaded OBF and the required format were different

Comment: The .pbf file is ungeoreferenced. For placing the tile on Earth the software must know a) the tiling schema and b) the name of the tile. If the common Web Mercator schema is used you can tell GDAL the location of the tile with opening options x, y, and z https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html#opening-options.

Comment: sorry, would you mind giving a use-case example of the above so I can ensure I am understanding correctly?

Comment: If you have a tile with z/x/y 12/2673/2048 around lat-lon (0,55) as the calculator https://developer.tomtom.com/map-display-api/documentation/zoom-levels-and-tile-grid shows, and you want to do something for it with ogr2ogr, you'd use a command `ogr2ogr -f some_format -oo z=12 -oo x=2673 -oo y=2048 output.xxx input.pbf`.